# How can I block auto scroll when I prepend some li in a ul in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I have this piece of code which prepend some li in a ul :

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
   var li = document.createElement('li');
   li.setAttribute(...);
   ... 

   /* add the new li in front of the ul */
   $("#listview").prepend(li);
}
```

When it is executed, the li are correctly added at the beginning my ul, but the page "auto scroll" stretch to the top of the ul. So, my question is : how can I do to prevent this auto scroll and stay at the same position of the list where I was before ? In advance, thanks you !

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. Could you maybe make a JSFiddle, or like to your site?
My JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kwscp/1/

Comment: Here a fiddle which shows what I want to correct : http://jsfiddle.net/4Ud5y/. When you click on the list, the new li are added but you are directly put at the top of the list. But I wish I could stay at the same position ...

Comment: It didn't scroll anywhere, the other elements just moved down. Do you want the elements on the bottom to, like, stay where they are?

Comment: Possible fix? http://jsfiddle.net/4Ud5y/1/ EDIT: Forgot to "Update" JSFiddle.

Comment: Yes, it's my wish :-) For example, at the begining, the top element of my screen is "Elem 1". After I clicked on the list, it's "29 - Hello World". I just want to add the new li at the top, without moving to the top like it.